# Collect thrown exceptions from CompletableFuture.allOf() execution

Tags: java, asynchronous, completable-future, java-threads

Having following scratch code:

```java
  public static void main(String[] args) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {

    CompletableFuture<Void> process1 = CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
      System.out.println("Process 1 with exception");
      throw new RuntimeException("Exception 1");
    });

    CompletableFuture<Void> process2 = CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
      System.out.println("Process 2 without exception");
    });

    CompletableFuture<Void> process3 = CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
      System.out.println("Process 3 with exception");
      throw new RuntimeException("Exception 3");
    });

    CompletableFuture<Void> allOfProcesses = CompletableFuture.allOf(process1, process2, process3);

    allOfProcesses.get();
  }
```

I'm looking for way how to collect all exceptions which have been thrown during parallel execution in `CompletableFuture.allOf()` and map it to List.

I know I can do this by returning exception (`CompletableFuture<Exception>`) instead of throwing and collect it by using `CompletableFuture::join` but I think throwing exception approach is better than returning and throwing it later

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want to avoid returning `CompletableFuture<Exception>` and just be able to first throw and than still be able to do something will exception collected from all of the `CompletableFuture`s.

In that case you can use [`CompletableFuture::exceptionally`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#exceptionally-java.util.function.Function-) to collect the exceptions:

```
private static List<Throwable> collectedExceptions = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());

public static void main(String[] args) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {

    CompletableFuture<Void> process1 = CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
        System.out.println("Process 1 with exception");
        throw new RuntimeException("Exception 1");
    }).exceptionally(exception -> {
        // Handle your exception here
        collectedExceptions.add(exception);
        return null;
    });

    CompletableFuture<Void> process2 = CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
        System.out.println("Process 2 without exception");
    });

    CompletableFuture<Void> process3 = CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
        System.out.println("Process 3 with exception");
        throw new RuntimeException("Exception 3");
    }).exceptionally(exception -> {
        // Handle your exception here
        collectedExceptions.add(exception);
        return null;
    });

    CompletableFuture<Void> allOfProcesses = CompletableFuture.allOf(process1, process2, process3);

    allOfProcesses.get();
    assert (collectedExceptions.size() == 2);
}
```

Comment: Right, fixed that